# ODBC 4 and ODBC Driver 17

Tags: sql-server, database, odbc

I want to check if ODBC 4 (https://github.com/microsoft/ODBC-Specification) and ODBC 17 Driver (msodbcsql17.dll) are interlinked or ODBC Driver 17 supports the queries for ODBC 4. Any link or help will be appreciated.
P.S.:- ODBC 4 was rolled out in 2016 and ODBC 17 in 2017.

Comment: What is your question here exactly? It appears you're asking for an off site resource, which is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am just asking for help if anybody knows and can help me out on this. I am not able to find anything which can prove they are interlinked.

Comment: JDBC https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwi8g5fI36v9AhWwjGgJHTB6C-EYABACGgJ3Zg&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAASJeRoFfD25Brv2QUTqkAjJjSq4iTNqGtfFpfG9GCvFnxuoazBN00&sig=AOD64_0MTfBAI-SrVK4cuaOLaoIcd_oJ6A&q&adurl&ved=2ahUKEwi9hZHI36v9AhXB9LsIHSxhDAo4ChDRDHoECAkQAQ

Comment: ATN2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/atn2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: "ODBC 4 was rolled out in 2016" really? I can not instantiate declare the version to be 4 even in the most recent windows in the year 2023.

Answer (score 1):

Using pyodbc to ask the driver what version of ODBC it supports, the driver replies with ODBC version 3.8:

```python
print(f'driver: {cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME)}, version: {cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_VER)}')
# driver: msodbcsql17.dll version 17.04.0001

print(f'driver ODBC version: {cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER)}')
# driver ODBC version: 03.80
```

Comment: Don't have python on my system.

Comment: You don't need Python on your system. I used Python on *my* system to query the driver and showed you the results.

Comment: I need to somehow prove that they are related, this gives me the version number only.